# TDE multiple master encryption keys within single schema

Tags: oracle, security

Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 enterprise.

We are hosting multiple customers data in single schema, a new customer wants his data to be secure with his unique encryption key.

Using Transparent Data Encryption (TDE), can we somehow create multiple master encryption keys within single schema?

We can upgrade to Oracle 11.2 for that as well if any workaround available.

Lastly if no such thing possible as 'multiple master encryption keys within single schema' then what other approach suits best for us, should we create separate database in same instance or should we commission separate vm-machine for this new customer.

Wishes